# Display files present in a folder in front end

Tags: java, javascript, web-applications, websphere

I have web app with middle tier in Java, front end in JS, angular.

Inside my war file the folder structure looks like:

```
myApp.war/css
myApp.war/images
myApp.war/js
myApp.war/files
```

files folder looks like:

```
myApp.war/files/file1.txt
myApp.war/files/file2.txt
```

Now in my app I have a button show files. Here I want to provide links to all the files present in files folder.

I am able to access file1.txt and file2.txt like this:

```
http://myserver.com:1225/myApp/files/file1.txt
http://myserver.com:1225/myApp/files/file2.txt
```

I can create links in my html and I will be done but the problem is those file names will change dynamically. So I can't guess how many files are present in files folder and their names.

So, wondering if I can display all files present in files folder with links.

I am getting **Error 404: SRVE0190E: File not found** when I access **http://myserver.com:1225/myApp/files/**

Any thoughts

Comment: You can use a web server like apache for listing the files inside a directory.

Comment: I am using websphere. I am able to access flles but not directories

Comment: I mean web server, not app server.

Comment: Directory browsing is disabled by default in WebSphere for security reasons. That's true for most web servers.

Comment: I remember doing directory browsing using tomcat... Do you think tomcat can help?

Comment: I was not talking about apache tomcat, I was talking about apache httpd static web server, wich automatically lists files inside its directory. But you can probably list files un java too: stackoverflow.com/questions/5694385/getting-the-filenames-of-all-files-in-a-folder

Comment: @JavaMan - This IBM document might help. See item 6.  [Advanced security hardening in WebSphere](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/1303_lansche/1303_lansche.html).

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable directory browsing for your application. In the WEB-INF create file `ibm-web-ext.xml` with the following content (the key element is `<enable-directory-browsing value="true"/>`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-ext
   xmlns="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee   http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee/ibm-web-ext_1_1.xsd"
   version="1.1">

   <reload-interval value="3"/>
   <enable-directory-browsing value="true"/>
   <enable-file-serving value="true"/>
   <enable-reloading value="true"/>
   <enable-serving-servlets-by-class-name value="false" />
</web-ext>
```